# why does the zip folder is not created with PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a existing folder to a zip and download it using php. The existing folder contain some files. This is my code

```
$folder = 'excel/report/[line: '.$args_line.'][startDate: '.$start_date.'][endDate: '.$end_date.']';
$zip_name = 'excel/report/[line: '.$args_line.'][startDate: '.$start_date.'][endDate: '.$end_date.'].zip';

$zip = new ZipArchive; 

if($zip -> open($zip_name, ZipArchive::CREATE ) === TRUE) { 

    $dir = opendir($folder); 

    while($file = readdir($dir)) { 
        if(is_file($folder.$file)) { 
            $zip -> addFile($folder.$file, $file); 
        } 
    } 
    $zip ->close(); 
}
```

But when i called the API zip folder is not created. Please go through my code and help me to solve it. Thanks in advance

Comment: You should avoid special characters like `:` in the names. Some OS's doesn't support it.  Do you get any errors? Checked the web servers error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    // Get real path for our folder
    $rootPath = realpath('folder-to-zip');

    // Initialize archive object
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zip->open('file.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

    // Create recursive directory iterator
    /** @var SplFileInfo[] $files */
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
    );

    foreach ($files as $name => $file)
    {
        // Skip directories (they would be added automatically)
        if (!$file->isDir())
        {
            // Get real and relative path for current file
            $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
            $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);

            // Add current file to archive
            $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
        }
    }

    // Zip archive will be created only after closing object
    $zip->close();
```

Comment: can i know how to download the zip folder after creating it ?

Comment: **You just need to add this after your code.**    
`header('Content-Type: application/zip');`    
`header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=file.zip');`    
`header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));`    
`readfile($zipname);`    
_As file.zip is name of file we initialized. You can make a dynamically._

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
$folder = 'excel/report/[line: '.$args_line.'][startDate: '.$start_date.'][endDate: '.$end_date.']';
$zip_name = 'excel/report/[line: '.$args_line.'][startDate: '.$start_date.'][endDate: '.$end_date.'].zip';

$zip = new ZipArchive; 

$zip->open($zip_name, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach (glob($folder) as $file) {
    $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();
```

Comment: A good answer includes a proper explanation of what you've changed and why. You also instantiate the ZipArchive twice. And why did you remove `if`-statement that checked if the zip archive was successfully created or not before trying to add files to it?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the zip file is still not created after executing this code. do i need to enable or add anything (like requre once) at the beginning?

Comment: as answer is already marked. @Magnus first purpose was to create zip file. validations can be added later.